# Is my understanding of skip-gram model correct?

Tags: nlp

I just learnt the skip-gram model, but I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct.

**Here is my understanding:**

There are two independent parts in the skip-gram model:

1. Given a single sentence (as a training example), we find the set of  "word pair".

   The way of finding the word pairs is:

   For each word in the sentence, we treat it as a centre word. For each centre word, we find its N context words which are within a given window (a hyperparameter). Then, for a single centre word, we have N word pairs which look like (centre word, context word)
2. Based on the given text, we find the vocabulary which is a set of size M. Say the dimension of the feature space is d (which is a hyperparameter), we construct two matrices A and B.

   `A = (c_1, c_2, ..., c_M)` and `B = (e_1, e_2, ..., e_M)` 
   are both `d by M` matrices. Matrix A stores the representation of each word in the vocabulary when it is a centre word, matrix B stores the representation of each word when it is a context word. By taking the inner product, for a centre word i we will have the inner product vector `inner = (c_i^{T}e_1, c_i^{T}e_2, ..., c_i^{T}e_M)^{T}`.

   Then for constructing the objective function (for centre word i), we should use the constructed word pairs in Step 1 for deciding which entries of the column vector `inner` we should take into account. (I omitted the part of softmax)

Is my understanding correct? Any suggestions are appreciated.